# Display query result in a table

Tags: carto-js, carto-js-v4

How can I retrieve the result of a SQL query from a source?

I would like to create a dynamic table that displays the result of a query.

```
 const source= new carto.source.SQL('SELECT cartodb_id, country, pop, the_geom_webmercator, the_geom FROM country');

const layer= new carto.layer.Layer(source, style, {
    featureOverColumns: ['cartodb_id', 'country', 'pop', 'the_geom']
});

layer.on('featureOver', data => {
    console.log(data);
});

 source.setQuery('SELECT * FROM country WHERE pop > 10000')
        .catch(cartoError => {
        console.log(cartoError)
        })
        .then(success => {
            //Display result
            console.log(success); //undefined
        });
```

I can't get the result back. 
setQuery returns a Promise object, but it undefined.

I guess I miss something... any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CARTO.js does not retrieve raw data from the account, on that code you are just setting the map data definition.

To get raw data you need to use the [SQL API](https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/). There is no dedicated SDK for that API because of its extreme simplicity. You have code examples on using `fetch` and other libraries to do that on this [help center article](https://carto.com/help/working-with-data/sql-api/).

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO.